# Transformation matrices for basis and coordinate transformation in non-orthonormal coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

The transformation matrices for covariant and contravariant vectors are different but in orthonormal coordinate system numerical values in matrices turn out to be same although in mathematical proof they are related by the operation of transpose of inverse of one of the matrix.

1. I wanna know how in any non-orthogonal coordinate system these two transformation matrices won't be same?
2. Also how are they same in any orthonormal coordinate system except Cartesian type coordinate system?

Comment: In an orthonormal coordinate basis the transpose is the same as the inverse for a linear transformation.

Comment: this is what i wanna know; how they are not same in non orthogonal coordinate system

Comment: In a non-orthonormal basis, the determinant need not equal 1, which affects the inverse operation...

Comment: thanks, ur ans has  given me a right direction to think about this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we start with an [orthonormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis) cartesian coordinate basis with unit vectors $\left( \hat{\mathbf{x}}, \hat{\mathbf{y}}, \hat{\mathbf{z}} \right)$.  Suppose we wish to rotate to a new coordinate system (may or may not be a coordinate [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)), see the following [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/199453/59023) which has a good discussion on the difference) with unit vectors $\left( \hat{\boldsymbol{\eta}}, \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}, \hat{\boldsymbol{\zeta}} \right)$.

If we define a rotation matrix, $\mathbb{A}$, from our original basis to the new coordinate system as the following:
$$
\mathbb{A} = \left[
\begin{array}{ c c c }
  \eta{\scriptstyle_{x}}     & \eta{\scriptstyle_{y}}     & \eta{\scriptstyle_{z}}      \\
  \beta{\scriptstyle_{x}} & \beta{\scriptstyle_{y}} & \beta{\scriptstyle_{z}}  \\
  \zeta{\scriptstyle_{x}} & \zeta{\scriptstyle_{y}} & \zeta{\scriptstyle_{z}}
\end{array} \right]  \tag{1}
$$
then we expect that $\mathbb{A}$ should satisfy the following if it is an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix):
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{A} \cdot \hat{\boldsymbol{\eta}} & = \langle 1, 0, 0 \rangle  \tag{2a}  \\
  \mathbb{A} \cdot \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} & = \langle 0, 1, 0 \rangle  \tag{2b}  \\
  \mathbb{A} \cdot \hat{\boldsymbol{\zeta}} & = \langle 0, 0, 1 \rangle  \tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$

If Equations 2a-2c are not satisfied, that implies that $\mathbb{A}$ is not orthogonal.  One consequence of this is that the magnitude of its [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) is not unity.

In the event that $\mathbb{A}$ is not orthogonal, but is still [invertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix), then the proper rotation matrix from the original $\left( \hat{\mathbf{x}}, \hat{\mathbf{y}}, \hat{\mathbf{z}} \right)$ coordinate system to the new $\left( \hat{\boldsymbol{\eta}}, \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}, \hat{\boldsymbol{\zeta}} \right)$ coordinate system is given by the inverse of the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of $\mathbb{A}$, or:
$$
\mathbb{R} = \left( \mathbb{A}^{T} \right)^{-1} \tag{3}
$$

We know that any invertible matrix satisfies $\left( \mathbb{A}^{T} \right)^{-1} = \left( \mathbb{A}^{-1} \right)^{T}$ and orthogonal matrices satisfy $\mathbb{A}^{T} = \mathbb{A}^{-1}$.  Thus, if $\left( \hat{\boldsymbol{\eta}}, \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}, \hat{\boldsymbol{\zeta}} \right)$ were an orthonormal basis we would have:
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{R} & = \left( \mathbb{A}^{-1} \right)^{T} \tag{4a} \\
  & = \left( \mathbb{A}^{T} \right)^{T} \tag{4b} \\
  & = \mathbb{A} \tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Can you clarify the definition of $\mathbb{R}$?  It sounds like you are defining it to be the same as $\mathbb{A}$: the transformation from old to new coordinates.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix - No, not in general.  $\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{A}$ if the unit vectors comprising $\mathbb{A}$ are orthonormal, otherwise Equation 4a is the general form (if $\mathbb{A}$ is invertible).  It is true that $\mathbb{R}$ is supposed to represent the general transformation matrix, but it need not be equivalent to $\mathbb{A}$.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: Sorry, not quite.  You write, "we define a rotation matrix, $\mathbb{A}$, from our original basis to the new coordinate system" and you also write, "then the proper rotation matrix from the original [...] coordinate system to the new [...] coordinate system [...] $\mathbb{R}$".  I still don't understand what the difference is between these two.  Is there a difference between "a rotation matrix" and "the proper rotation matrix"?

Comment: Ugh, sorry, poor phrasing on my part.  I meant to imply that in the event that $\mathbb{A}$ is not orthogonal, then it is not the rotation matrix from the XYZ to the new coordinate system.  It is only the rotation matrix in the special case when it is orthogonal.  The equivalence of $\mathbb{A}$ with $\mathbb{R}$ only results because of linear algebra identities for invertible and orthogonal matrices.  It's a somewhat backwards way of phrasing it but there is a logical reason for it.  I often use this type of algorithm for rotating data in different heliographic coordinate systems.

Comment: Or wait, were you asking why I used the specific words "rotation matrix" for something that may not be orthonormal?  If so, that is just careless nomenclature on my part, unfortunately.

Comment: Primarily the first (but I think related to the second) is exactly my confusion.  Let's assume $\mathbb{A}$ is *not* orthogonal.  Then it is not a "rotation matrix" (formally).  But it is still the "transformation" between old and new coordinates (which seemed to be its definition)?  Either way $\mathbb{R} \neq \mathbb{A}$, then what (physically) does $\mathbb{R}$ represent?  Given that $\mathbb{A}$ is *not* orthonormal, is $\mathbb{A}^{-1}$ still the transformation from *new* to *old* coordinates?  Or is it $\mathbb{R} = \left( \mathbb{A}^T \right)^{-1}$.  Thanks, and sorry for so many '?'s!

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix - No worries.  If $\mathbb{A}$ is not orthogonal, then construct $\mathbb{A}$ but then define and use $\mathbb{R}$ to rotate 3-vectors.  You can go through and try this out and see that one will not give the correct results while the other will if $\mathbb{A}$ is not orthogonal.  Typically I use two known vectors like the magnetic field and bulk flow velocity of the solar wind, which need not be orthogonal.  I can use the two vectors to construct an orthonormal basis with rotation matrix $\mathbb{R}$ from old to new.

Comment: Interesting!  I think this might be the problem I'm having here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/522761/8521 .   Thanks again

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix - Okay, I think I have at least more clues about this.  I went back to my copy of "Elementary Linear Algebra" by Anton and Rorres and looked at Chapter 6, Section 5 (pages 320-330).  It seems that $\mathbb{R}$ is always the proper choice but that it usually is just $\mathbb{A}$ since one usually uses orthogonormal input vectors.  The inverse normalizes a non-normalized matrix and the transpose undoes the index changes introduced by the inverse (at least I think this is the implication).