# Trouble finding the (inverse) transformations between covariant and contravariant components

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-frames, relativity

Consider a point in cartesian and polar coordinates, $P = \{x,y\} = \{r,\theta\}$, such that $x = r \cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$.  I have an arbitrary vector (e.g. a velocity vector) at point $P$, and I know it's cooridnates in cartesian coordinates, $\vec{v} = a^i e_i = a^0 e_0 + a^1 e_1$, where $e_i = \{\hat{x}, \hat{y}\}$, and I want to find the components in a bases that is the polar tangent vectors, $e'_i = \{\hat{r},\hat{\theta}\}$, i.e. $\vec{v} = a^{\prime i} e'_i = a^{\prime 0} e'_0 + a^{\prime 1} e_1$.

*(Ultimately I need to do this exercise in 3D spherical coordinates, and do a couple of coordinate rotations in between, but I think this case encompasses my [current] confusion)*.

---

Attempt:

I can **define** a transformation between coordinates based on,
$$e'_j = e_i \, {S^i}_j = e_i \frac{\partial e'_j}{\partial e_i},$$

for example, $e'_0 = \hat{r} = \frac{\partial}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}.$

Thus the **tensor that transforms the bases** $\{\hat{x},\hat{y}\} \rightarrow \{\hat{r},\hat{\theta}\}$, can be calculated as

$${S^i}_j = \pmatrix{\frac{\partial e'_0}{\partial e_0} & \frac{\partial e'_1}{\partial e_0} \\ \frac{\partial e'_0}{\partial e_1} & \frac{\partial e'_1}{\partial e_1}} = \pmatrix{\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}} = \pmatrix{\cos\theta & -\frac{1}{r} \sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \frac{1}{r} \cos\theta},$$

and the values of $r,\theta$ here are, again, fixed based on the point $P$.  Using this, we immediately get, $e'_i = \{\hat{r}, \hat{\theta} \} = \{\hat{x}\cos\theta + \hat{y}\sin\theta, \,\, - (\hat{x}/r)\sin\theta + (\hat{y}/r) \cos\theta \}$, which matches what I get from geometry.  So this seems good.

The components of the vectors transform contravariantly, and so the transformation should be given by, ${T^i}_j = \partial e_j \, / \, \partial e'_i$.  Going through the same procedure, I find the **components of the tensor that transforms the coordinates** $\{a_0,a_1\} \rightarrow \{a'_0, a'_1\}$ as,

$${T^i}_j = \pmatrix{\frac{\partial e_0}{\partial e'_0} & \frac{\partial e_1}{\partial e'_0} \\ \frac{\partial e_0}{\partial e'_1} & \frac{\partial e_1}{\partial e'_1}} = \pmatrix{\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}} = \pmatrix{\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -r \sin\theta & r \cos\theta}.$$

Now if we try this, we immediately get a problem: $a^{\prime i} = \{x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta, \,\, -rx\sin\theta + ry\cos\theta \}$.  The 0th component seems fine, but the 1st has the wrong dimensions: length squared instead of dimensionless!

I also notice that while $T S = \mathbb{I}$ (the identity matrix), and thus $T = S^{-1}$, also $S T \neq \mathbb{I}$, i.e. $S \neq T^{-1}$...

Am I missing a transpose somewhere?  Or am I assuming an orthonormality somewhere where it doesn't exist?  Any help or pointers (even on improper terminology / syntax) is much appreciated!

---

Edit: Rows-vs-columns, and left-vs-right matrix multiplication has always confused me, so I'm primarily following the indices and their positions, but I've still tried to be consistent with rows and columns. One "reason" to add a transpose, however, could be that while the inverse matrix should transform the components (as apposed to bases), the components are 'columns' while the bases 'rows', so perhaps that adds a transpose? But where does this come from in index notation?

Comment: Maybe it's the mixture of up and down indices, but your T matrix representation looks like the transpose of what I'm used to seeing

Comment: @KyleKanos yeah, and I think taking the transpose would fix the problem I identified, but I don't see *why* that would be appropriate.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix - Ah, this is why you were asking about the other question (https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/231765/59023).  Is $r$ a radial distance or some, non-unity value?  If so, then $T^{i}_{j}$ is not orthonormal since the determinant would not be unity, correct?  I spent quite a while digging through my linear algebra textbook and online resources trying to figure out why the non-orthogonality changes the rotation matrix definitions but I don't recall finding an answer.  It's almost certainly something a mathematician would laughingly answer not knowing why it wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: @honeste_vivere exactly how I've been feeling!  $r$ is a not-necessarily-unity radial distance, so neither $T$ nor $S$ is (necessarily) orthonormal.  I might try that question on math.SE, but this has really helped narrow down what exactly the problem is!

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be $\mathrm e_i'=(\partial x^j/\partial x_i')\mathrm e_j=$? You use what I have at least for defining $S$ and $T$ (i.e., using $x,\,y$, etc), but defined it wrongly (at least as I understand it) before that.

Comment: @KyleKanos, aren't those the same?  $e_i = \partial / \partial x^i$, thus, $\partial e'_i / \partial e_j = \partial x^j / \partial x^{\prime i}$, right?

Comment: Eh, I guess. But it looks weird to me to write it that way.

Comment: But I think you've just done some derivative mistakes. Your $T$ matrix has $\partial y/\partial r=-r\sin\theta$ which isn't right. Similarly, your $\partial x/\partial\theta$ (which you didn't fix when copying) shows no $r$ dependence when it should.

Comment: @KyleKanos that seems to have been a typo just in the middle form of the T matrix (i.e. the left and right versions **I think** are still correct - and match up).  $\partial e_0 / \partial e'_1$ should have been (and now is corrected to) $\partial x / \partial \theta$ instead of $\partial y / \partial r$; fixed a similars typo in $S$ also.

Comment: Okay, well coordinate transformations I'm familiar with are the transpose of what you've written. I'm currently looking at Snygg's text on Diff Geom via Clifford Alg & it says the $x_i$ run across while the $x_j'$ run down.

Comment: But like I said in my first comment, that could be because you're using mixed indices. I have to think some more on it though.