# Meaning and application of the connection coefficients (Christoffel symbols)

Tags: differential-geometry

I know that in polar coordinates, it is
$\frac{\partial \,{{\mathbf{e}}_{r}}}{\partial \theta }={{\mathbf{e}}_{\theta }}$ and $\frac{\partial \,{{\mathbf{e}}_{\theta }}}{\partial \theta }=-{{\mathbf{e}}_{r}}$
where ${{\mathbf{e}}_{r}}$ and ${{\mathbf{e}}_{\theta }}$ are the basis unit vectors.

Anyway, using the definition of the connection coefficients (Christoffel symbols) it should also be

$\frac{\partial \,{{\mathbf{e}}_{r}}}{\partial \theta }={{\Gamma }^{r}}_{r\theta }\,{{\mathbf{e}}_{r}}+{{\Gamma }^{\theta }}_{r\,\theta }\,{{\mathbf{e}}_{\theta }}$ and
$\frac{\partial \,{{\mathbf{e}}_{\theta }}}{\partial \theta }={{\Gamma }^{r}}_{\theta \,\theta }\,{{\mathbf{e}}_{r}}+{{\Gamma }^{\theta }}_{\theta \,\theta }\,{{\mathbf{e}}_{\theta }}$

And since it is ${{\Gamma }^{r}}_{\theta \,\theta }=-r$ , ${{\Gamma }^{\theta }}_{r\,\theta }=\frac{1}{r}$ , ${{\Gamma }^{r}}_{r\,\theta }=0$, ${{\Gamma }^{\theta }}_{\theta \,\theta }=0$    (calculated with the metric)
it should be

$\frac{\partial \,{{\mathbf{e}}_{r}}}{\partial \theta }=\frac{1}{r}{{\mathbf{e}}_{\theta }}$ and $\frac{\partial \,{{\mathbf{e}}_{\theta }}}{\partial \theta }=-r\,{{\mathbf{e}}_{r}}$

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using two different sets of basis vectors.  $\frac{\partial\mathbf e_r}{\partial \theta} = \mathbf e_\theta$ and $\frac{\partial \mathbf e_\theta}{\partial \theta} = -\mathbf e_r$ hold for the orthonormal polar basis, in which the metric takes the form

$$g_{ij} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}$$

The connection coefficients you quote arise from the polar coordinate basis $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial r},\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right\}$ which is **not** orthonormal, and in which the metric takes the form

$$g_{ij} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & r^2}$$

The two bases are related via $\mathbf e_r = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and $\mathbf e_\theta = r\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}$.

---

An important thing to recognize is that the basis $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial r},\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right\}$ arises naturally as the basis induced by the polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$.  On the other hand, the orthonormal basis $\{e_r,e_\theta\}$ is **not** induced by a coordinate system; there is no set of coordinates $(u,v)$ such that $e_r = \frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ and $e_\theta =\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$.  This is an example of a [non-holonomic basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_basis).

The reason that this is important is that in your first pass through GR, you will likely start off by using holonomic bases exclusively.  Accidentally using a non-holonomic basis can lead to some apparent contradictions.

Comment: yes, and just to be clear: the vectors in the two sets have same directions but different sizes

Comment: @AndrewSteane Yes, thanks.  I've added to my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: j-murray, @AndrewSteane
Thanks. It's all more clear now. I didn't expect such subtleties between the polar coordinate basis vectors (not unitary) and the polar unit vectors (not a coordinate basis). Now I know I must be careful...Many thanks. It's all more clear now. I didn't expect such subtleties in the difference between the polar coordinate basis vectors (not unitary) and the polar unit vectors (not a coordinate basis). Now I know I must be careful...

Comment: This other related post can be useful:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/198280/what-coordinate-systems-allows-the-magnitude-of-the-basis-vectors-to-change-with